# primeNg Schedule (calendar) Issue loading the Calendar for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, primeng

I'm trying to implement Primeng Schedule component. from their doc it's one particularity that requires third party api (Moment , FullCalendar).
So I included the dependencies, even installed @types/jquery but I get this error whenever I run the app:

> ERROR TypeError: e.addClass is not a function
>       at t.initialRender (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
>       at t.render (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
>       at Schedule.push../node_modules/primeng/components/schedule/schedule.js.Schedule.initialize (schedule.js:222)
>       at Schedule.push../node_modules/primeng/components/schedule/schedule.js.Schedule.ngAfterViewChecked (schedule.js:208)
>       at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:9355)
>       at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:9326)
>       at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:9316)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10252)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:10484)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10447)

it seems like a jquery issue but I ensured it's there and loaded, I also used the data source and the sample code from the official primeNg showcase.

Data source :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.events = [
        {
            "title": "All Day Event",
            "start": "2016-01-01"
        },
        {
            "title": "Long Event",
            "start": "2016-01-07",
            "end": "2016-01-10"
        },
        {
            "title": "Repeating Event",
            "start": "2016-01-09T16:00:00"
        },
        {
            "title": "Repeating Event",
            "start": "2016-01-16T16:00:00"
        },
        {
            "title": "Conference",
            "start": "2016-01-11",
            "end": "2016-01-13"
        }
    ];
}
```

Here's the component template :

```html
<div class= "title" *ngIf="events">
  <p-schedule [events]="events"></p-schedule>  
</div>>
```

And the dependencies in **angular.json** :

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",

          //NG PRIME
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"
        ]
```

Got a suggestion to use an older version, but I'm hoping I can work things around with the current version to avoid missing security/bugs updates.

Thanks for your time and hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing `fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha` solved issue for me !

Part of my angular.json:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
          "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"
        ]
```

I hope it will help you too !

Comment: Works perfectly man, thanks alot!

**npm** : npm install fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha

Comment: fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha is not ready yet. There is a bug with the dayClick event:

event is not fired when clicking on some late times (preoduce by clicking on 11pm)
times are often chifted by 30 minutes

Comment: Here is the reference of the bug [https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4221]. It happens when the window containing the calendar is scrolled. We need to find a way to make primng work with fullcalendar v3

Comment: You can workaround the problem of  fullcalendar v4 by keeping the calendar small enough so that the window has no scroll bar.

In the template:
`[height]="customHeightOfCalendar" 
(onViewRender)="handleViewRender($event)"`

In the component:

`handleViewRender(e) {
    this.customHeightOfCalendar = window.innerHeight * 0.85; 
  }`